# How to password protect wordpress site?

Tags: wordpress

I need to password protect my wordpress site except home page. I need homepage to be visible to every visitor but if they click on ANY link that could be post/page within the site then user should be redirected to login page. Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
if (is_user_logged_in()){
    echo "Welcome, registered user, here are my lovely posts";
}
else {
    header( 'Location: http://www.yoursite.com/login.php' ) ;
};
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just a bit of edit to benhowdle89's code..

```
<?php
if (is_user_logged_in() || is_home()){
    echo "Welcome, registered user, here are my lovely posts";
}
else {
    header( 'Location: http://www.yoursite.com/wp-login.php' ) ;
};
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

[WordPress › Absolute Privacy « WordPress Plugins](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/absolute-privacy/)